# Unable to define class for entry fields in Tkinter

Tags: python, class, oop, tkinter, widget

I'm a Python novice. So I'm coding a GUI, and as part of that, I want to specify bindings for entry widgets. Since the commands I want the entry widgets to initiate when a certain event occurs are similar, I thought it would save space and effort if I could define all entry fields to be part of a class, named, say, FIELDS. Then, I could define a method as part of that class which prints the result of applying the get function to it. Following is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
class FIELDS(Entry): 
'''
Inherits from Entry class so that methods like pack() can be used
'''
    def x(event): #method to print what was typed in the entry field.
        print(str(self.get())) #prints the input text

root = Tk()
entry_field = Entry(root)
entry_field = FIELDS()
entry_field.pack()
entry_field.bind('<Return>', FIELDS.x)
root.mainloop
```

On implementing this, however, I receive an error: name 'self' is not defined. The full error is actually a quite long and I can share it if required (not doing so to keep the question brief). In the instantiation, I passed entry_field as self. Why am I receiving this error and how may I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several problems in your code.

1. the docstring is indented incorrectly. It needs to be indented the same as the code in the class.
2. You need to define `x` to include the `self` parameter. This isn't a tkinter-specific requirement, that's just how classes work in python.
3. you need to call the method on the instance, not on the class. You need to change the binding to `entry_field.bind('', entry_field.x)